# Time difference between two rows for specified ID

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm trying to find the time difference in seconds between two rows that have the same ID.

Here's a simple table.

[image]

The table is ordered by `myid` and `timestamp`. I'm trying to get the total second between two rows that have the same `myid`.

Here's what I have come up with. The only problem with this query is that it calculates the time difference for all records but not for the same ID.

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(second, pTimeStamp, TimeStamp), q.*
FROM    (
            SELECT  *,
            LAG(TimeStamp) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp) pTimeStamp
            FROM    data
        ) q
WHERE   pTimeStamp IS NOT NULL
```

This is the output.

[image]

I only want the output highlighted in yellow.

Any suggestions?

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc3a5/3)

Comment: Add `partition by ID`

Comment: "Tables" are not ordered by anything, queries and result-sets are.  Nowhere in your query are you either ordering nor partitioning by ID, so the results are not ordered by ID either.

Comment: @shawnt00 Thank you! That what I needed. If you write your comment as answer, I'll accepted as correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix is simply a matter of narrowing the window, with `PARTITION BY`, to rows with the same `ID`:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(second, pTimeStamp, TimeStamp), q.*
FROM    (
            SELECT  *,
            LAG(TimeStamp) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TimeStamp) pTimeStamp
            FROM    data
        ) q
WHERE   pTimeStamp IS NOT NULL
```